# Rosyln compiling strongly named assembly at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

i'm using CSharpCompilation and passing in options using CSharpCompilationOptions.
One of the options i'd like to use is providing a StrongNameProvider. it's an abstract class that i don't know how to implement.

does anybody know how this class would be implemented?

Comment: Can you use [`DesktopStrongNameProvider`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/6181abfdf59da26da27f0dbedae2978df2f83768/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/StrongName/DesktopStrongNameProvider.cs)?

Comment: thanks DavidG, looks like i can use that if i have a key file. now i need to find out how to dynamically create key file to sign with

Comment: this project looks useful, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2004/12/03/managed-strongname-refactoring-complete/

Comment: will just use sn.exe and call it from app to generate signed key file